# How can I solve the 404 object not found error?

Tags: xampp, laravel-5.8

I'm using `laravel` and `xampp` for my web app. I've created a few page with the routes. Somehow when I went to that page, I got `error 404` message.
I've checked the path and nothing wrong with it. Somebody please help me..this is my routes

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/public/employer', 'Employer@index')->name('employer.show');

Route::get('/home/profile', 'ProfilesController@index')- 
>name('profile.show');
Route::get('/home/profile/edit', 'ProfilesController@edit')- 
>name('profile.edit');
```

and this is the link
    http://localhost/home/profile

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Please [edit] the question to include the code for your routes, and a description of how your folder structure is set up.

Comment: Please share your routes and url that you are using! So Someone can read and help if they can. No one is magician here. :) We all are human.